# Replacing global variable and synchronized block with realm

Tags: android, concurrency, realm, synchronized

I rephrased the question in order not to confuse people on what I am really doing. The example used in the original question was way too simplified.

My project is client/server based. The android app is the client. To properly simply the situation, we can think about that I have two intents/activities and one background thread. Activity A is login . Activity B is where the rest of the app is. The background thread is a socket thread, and it needs to be kept up all the time until user exits the app, or network connection is interrupted.

A state machine is implemented to handle the app states, and this state machine is required by all activities, and the socket thread.

Singleton easily meets the requirement of my design, but there will be a lot of synchronized block and wait statement. I wonder is it possible to use realm to achieve the same goal

---

### Original Question

I am new to Realm Java (Android) development. In my current code, I have a bunch of global variables and using them in a few AsyncTask or background threads.

I'll use some code here to demostrate my example

```
//Class holding global variable
public class GlobalInfo{
    public static String info;
}

//Class changing the global variable
class A{
    void doSomething(){
        String info = GlobalInfo.info;
        info = "start";
        synchronized(info){                
            ...... //do something
            info = "done";
            info.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

//background thread waiting for info to be "done". Neglecting the class holding it
void doSomethingAfterDone(){
    String info = GlobalInfo.info;
    synchronized(info){                
        while(!info.Equals("done")){
            info.wait();
        }
        //do something
    }
}
```

Assume that when `doSomethingAfterDone()` is called, the method `doSomething()` is still running. Therefore, the `doSomethingAfterDone()` will be waiting for `doSomething()` to notify before exiting the `while` loop.

Is it possible to use Realm to replace them? For example, using a realm transaction + a listener waiting for change, rather than applying synchronized block on the global variable and wait for its notification?

I found `Realm.waitForChange()` will block the execution until there is a changed made to it. However, do all changes that apply to any objects registered or copied to realm returns true for this statement, regardless what get changed?

I know that I can pass String between intents, but I want to know if it is feasible that realm can do the job.

Comment: Well, you can definitely replace the writes to the global String with a write to the Realm, and then listen to changes in the Realm. I haven't had a global variable beyond checking process death for a very long time now. Personally, I don't see what you need the "daemon thread" for which constantly loops and listens to the global variable - you could just run the task when you'd be setting `done` to `true`.

Comment: The code sample you posted doesn't really use Realm, but if info is a RealmObject you are setting some field one, I would definetely use a RealmChangeListener for it. The listener would trigger for all changes the the same type of objects currently, but it should be easily checkable if the valid should be "done" before you proceed.

Comment: @Joe I think this is theoretically possible if the socket thread is a looper thread that is set to auto-update. But I have never actually tried to set up a looper and terminate it when there are no open activities left. Your best bet is looking into HandlerThread.

Comment: Thank you very much @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 0):

Well you generally don't need global variables at all. You can just write to the Realm on the background thread, and listen for change on the UI thread.

```
//Class holding global variable
//public class GlobalInfo{
    //public static String info;
//}

//Class changing the global variable
class A{
    void doSomething(){
        //String info = GlobalInfo.info;
        //info = "start";
        //synchronized(info){                
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() { // assuming background thread
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    //!! do something with Realm
                }
            });
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() { // could be merged to this background thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
               doSomethingAfterDone();
            }
        }).start();
            //info = "done";
            //info.notifyAll();
        //}
    }
}

//background thread waiting for info to be "done". Neglecting the class holding it
void doSomethingAfterDone(){
    //String info = GlobalInfo.info;
    //synchronized(info){                
        //while(!info.Equals("done")){
        //    info.wait();
        //}
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    //do something
                }
            });
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think what you wrote is what I meant. `doSomethingAfterDone` is in a completely separate class and thread. Both threads are referencing to the same stringz and they update/listen on the same string according to different states. Think about a a async task thread and a background thread, and a state machine: the user click something, so the Async Task get notified, updates the state and wait. The background thread gets the new state, do some logic and change the state again. Then the Async Task is notified that background thread is done, and updates the GUI

Comment: I know I can pass this state machine if the background thread is launched from the same GUI or Async Task thread, but what if I still need the background thread when switching to a new intent/activity, and the new GUI thread also needs this state machine?

Comment: Well while it's possible, I also think that sounds overengineered.

Comment: I updated my question, can you please kindly take a look
? Thanks.